# materialising data into custom dtos using linq to sql include and 3 hierarchical data levels

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have 3 tables linked in a master detail relationship, top level organisation table can have multiple sites, each site can have one or more meters.  This code works fine but If I try to materialise the data into custom dtos I cant gain access to the third level meters data.  I get an error

'ICollection does not contain a definition for Meters'

but there is meter data present, can anyone tell me where Im going wrong here?

```
var overView = await (from organisation in DbContext.Organisations select organisation)
                .Where(o => o.ID == request.Id)
                .Include(q => q.Sites.Select(t => t.Meters))
                .Select(item => new OrganisationAggregateDto
                {
                    Organisation = new OrganisationDto { Address1 = item.Address1, Address2 = item.Address2, Address3 = item.Address3, City = item.City, County = item.County, EmailFrom = item.EmailFrom, EmailIsSSL = item.EmailIsSSL, EmailPortNumber = item.EmailPortNumber, EmailServerHost = item.EmailServerHost, EmailServerUserName = item.EmailServerUserName, End_User_Org = item.End_User_Org, GroupId = item.GroupId, ID = item.ID, IsRetail = item.IsRetail, OrganisationName = item.OrganisationName, ParentOrganisationID = item.ParentOrganisationID, Postcode = item.Postcode, Role = item.Role, Status = item.Status, UserId = item.UserId, ParentOrganisationName = "", IsRetailNarrative = item.IsRetail == true ? "Yes" : "No", ContractType = item.ContractType, EmailAddress = item.EmailAddress },
                    Sites = item.Sites.Select(s => new Dto.Site.SiteDto { ADDRESS1 = s.ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2 = s.ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3 = s.ADDRESS3, ADDRESS4 = s.ADDRESS4, ADDRESS5 = s.ADDRESS5, End_User_Org = s.End_User_Org, ID = s.ID, POSTCODE = s.POSTCODE, LOCATION_NAME = s.LOCATION_NAME, COMMODITY = s.COMMODITY, CONTACT_EMAIL = s.CONTACT_EMAIL, CONTACT_FAX = s.CONTACT_FAX, CONTACT_NAME = s.CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_TEL = s.CONTACT_TEL, COUNTRY = s.COUNTRY, CUSTOMER_LOCATION_ID = s.CUSTOMER_LOCATION_ID, EAC = s.EAC, SUPPLY_CAPACITY_UOM = s.SUPPLY_CAPACITY_UOM, OrgId = s.OrgId, VOLTAGE = s.VOLTAGE }).ToList(),
                    Meters = item.Sites.Meters(m => new Dto.Meter.MeterDto { DURATIONTYPE = m.DURATIONTYPE, ID = m.ID, METER_TYPE = m.METER_TYPE, MPAN = m.MPAN, SiteID = m.SiteID, UNIT_OF_MEASURE = m.UNIT_OF_MEASURE, CAPACITY = m.CAPACITY, CUSTOMER_LOCATION_ID = m.CUSTOMER_LOCATION_ID, DFLT_DF_MR_DURATION_TYPE = m.DFLT_DF_MR_DURATION_TYPE, METER_SUPPLEMENTARY = m.METER_SUPPLEMENTARY }).ToList(),
                    ID = item.ID,
                    Contracts = null
                }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: can anyone help me out here ? Ive been stuck on this all morning

Comment: in case anyone else has a similar problem, I got an answer from a different forum   Meters = item.Sites.SelectMany(s => s.Meters).Select(m => new Dto.Meter.MeterDto { DURATIONTYPE = m.DURATIONTYPE, ID = m.ID, METER_TYPE = m.METER_TYPE, MPAN = m.MPAN, SiteID = m.SiteID, UNIT_OF_MEASURE = m.UNIT_OF_MEASURE, CAPACITY = m.CAPACITY, CUSTOMER_LOCATION_ID = m.CUSTOMER_LOCATION_ID, DFLT_DF_MR_DURATION_TYPE = m.DFLT_DF_MR_DURATION_TYPE, METER_SUPPLEMENTARY = m.METER_SUPPLEMENTARY }).ToList(),

Comment: SelectMany was the key